# Laravel Pivot Table Insert Array

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am not sure on the relationship for the **tasks_assigned_too_groups** table, 
my database is like the following:

```
tasks
id | task_name | task_description

groups
id | group_name | user_id

tasks_assigned_too_groups
id | tasks_id | group_name
```

in the form you create a task and specify it to groups, then I want to to create like the following:

```
 public function store() {

        $data = request()->validate([
           'task_title' => '',
           'task_description' => '',
           'start_date' => '',
            'due_date' => '',
            'group_name' => '',
        ]);

// insert in to tasks database table...
        $task = request()->user()->tasks()->create([
            'task_title' => $data['task_title'],
            'task_description' => $data['task_description'],
            'start_date' => $data['start_date'],
            'due_date' => $data['due_date'],
        ]);

// insert into tasks_assigned_too_groups database table...
        $task->setforgroups()->attach($data['group_name']);

        return new TasksResource($task);
    }
```

**$data['group_name']** is an array like following:

```
[
  {
    "group_name": "9x/En3"
  },
  {
    "group_name": "10x/En3"
  }
]
```

How do I insert the task_id and group_name its been assigned too into  tasks_assigned_too_groups table?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using the `group_name` attribute as foreign key in your pivot table? I'd advise rather not to. But anyways, assuming you have all the keys and relations set up properly, simply calling `attach($keys)` with `$keys` being an array/collection of foreign keys you want to assign, it should work properly.

Comment: @D.Petrov, this successfully inserts the group_name but not the task_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change this

```
 tasks
 id | task_name | task_description

 groups
 id | group_name | user_id

 tasks_assigned_too_groups
 id | tasks_id | group_name
```

to this:

```
 tasks
 id | task_name | task_description

 groups
 id | group_name | user_id

 tasks_assigned_too_groups
 id | tasks_id | group_id
```

Because this is **ManyToMany Relationship** and the *intermediary(pivot)* table needs to have a foreign key of both connected tables.

**Task** model

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
}
```

**Group** model

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task');
}
```

Here is the documentation for more info.
[laravel.com](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: thanks, I am getting the groups table from an api, where each user is assigned to a group_name so my thinking is keep the group_name as the unique id?

Comment: I suggest that the unique id of the group's table is the id column, group_name is not unique for some instances.

So, you can get the members of the group by adding the relation in the User model. 
ex: $group = Group::with('users')->find($group_id);